# Smart domain-masking, redirection or forwarding

Tags: dns, forwarding, domain-name

I rent a domain name, lets say `MyFakeDomain.com` (using GoDaddy, if it matters) and I rent a shared hosting that gave me an ugly url, lets say `ugly.long-url.123456789.com` (1and1.com, if it matters.)

As expected, when people go to `MyFakeDomain.com`, I want them to see the content of `ugly.long-url.123456789.com`. However, with the little I know about that, I was only able to do domain masking, but it also overrides all the webpage title by a static title. Even worse than that, if you go to `MyFakeDomain.com` and hover on a link, you would see `http://ugly.long-url.123456789.com\[ThatLink.html]`.

**What must I change in order to always hide the `ugly.long-url.123456789.com` from the users, and not overwrite the titles of every page?**

Is it something in the zone file and zone records? (A, CNAME, etc.) If so, any resources you know that could explain all this clearly to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was to change the Nameservers on the Domain registrar (GoDaddy) to point to the Nameservers of the Domain host (1and1.) This way, the latest handles all the underlying mechanism, and the domain registrar just delegates all his responsibilities on the host.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hosting environment and if you have access to `ugly.long-url.123456789.com`.

The basic idea behind this all is: you have the DNS system where you store A, CNAME, etc records. These records help the browser *identify the server* the site is hosted on. However, the server has to be configured to actually *handle that domain*, so it needs to know what content it should serve for `MyFakeDomain.com`.

If you have a proper hosting package for `ugly.long-url.123456789.com`, you should be able to add the domain to it. If in doubt, ask your hosting provider. This is the cleans and probably most stable way to do it. If you can't do this, you can't do it with just A and CNAME records.

If you do have for example a PHP hosting package you can redirect your nice address to, you could write a proxy script that forwards all requests to `ugly.long-url.123456789.com` and changes the links in the response to your nice domain name. This requires a bit of programming. A good starting point is the [curl documentation](http://php.net/curl).

If you don't have access to a PHP host for your nice domain, but you can deploy some basic HTML and JavaScript, you could change all your URL's on `ugly.long-url.123456789.com`. This link:

```
<a href="http://ugly.long-url.123456789.com/mysite.html">sometext</a>
```

becomes this:

```
<a href="http://MyFakeDomain.com/#/mysite.html&amp;title=This%20is%20my%20title" target="_top">sometext</a>
```

On `MyFakeDomain.com` you would then deploy a script that reads the hash part of the URL and loads an iframe for it. (`window.location.hash` in JS)